# UE4 C++ saving inventory TArray of item pointers across multiple levels

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a basic inventory system in UE4 using a TArray of pointers to my custom Item class. It works fine in individual levels, but when I open a new level, the inventory disappears. I've looked at multiple tutorials and posts about this issue and tried various solutions including migrating my inventory array to the Game Instance, and creating a SaveGame class that holds a copy of the array that saves before and loads after opening a level

After all these, inventory still disappears. My code has changed a lot so it's probably not that helpful but here are some snippets of my current solution.

Declaration in character header

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
    TArray<AItem*> Inventory_Space;
```

Declaration in SaveGame

```
UPROPERTY(SaveGame)
    TArray<AItem*> Inventory_Save;
```

Save and load functions in character implementation

```
void ABatteryManPlayer::SaveInventory()
{
    
    UBatteryMan_SaveGame* SaveInstance = Cast<UBatteryMan_SaveGame>
        (UGameplayStatics::CreateSaveGameObject(UBatteryMan_SaveGame::StaticClass()));

    for (int i = 0; i < INVENTORY_SIZE; i++) {
        SaveInstance->Inventory_Save[i] = Inventory_Space[i];
    }
    
    UGameplayStatics::SaveGameToSlot(SaveInstance, TEXT("Slot0"), 0);
}

void ABatteryManPlayer::LoadInventory()
{
    
    UBatteryMan_SaveGame* SaveInstance = Cast<UBatteryMan_SaveGame>
        (UGameplayStatics::CreateSaveGameObject(UBatteryMan_SaveGame::StaticClass()));

    UBatteryMan_SaveGame* SaveInstance = Cast<UBatteryMan_SaveGame>
        (UGameplayStatics::LoadGameFromSlot("Slot0",0));

    for (int i = 0; i < INVENTORY_SIZE; i++) {
        Inventory_Space[i] = SaveInstance->Inventory_Save[i];
    }
}
```

Saving after game timer goes to 0 (character implementation)

```
CurrentTime--;
    if (CurrentTime == 0) {

        SaveInventory();
        Instance->Levels_Complete++;

        if (Instance->Levels_Complete < Instance->NUM_LEVELS) {

            FName Level_Name = FName(TEXT("Level_" + FString::FromInt(++Instance->Levels_Complete)));
            UGameplayStatics::OpenLevel(this, Level_Name, false);

        }
```

Loading back into player inventory in GameMode

```
void ABatteryMan_GameMode::BeginPlay() {
    Super::BeginPlay();

    ABatteryManPlayer* Player = Cast<ABatteryManPlayer>(UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerCharacter(GetWorld(), 0));
    Player->LoadInventory();

    FTimerHandle UnusedHandle;
    GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(
        UnusedHandle, this, &ABatteryMan_GameMode::SpawnPlayerRecharge, FMath::RandRange(2,5), true);
}
```

Comment: when you call `SaveGameToSlot` in `SaveInventory`, can you check the return value to see if it returned true or false? that will tell whether or not the game was saved successfully. also, did you make a typo in your `LoadInventory` function? because you declare the `SaveInstance` variable in the same scope twice.

Comment: I printed a debug message and it said that it saved successfully. Also that is a typo, I've been shifting code around a lot.

Comment: is `AItem` of type `AActor`?

Comment: And could you also try attaching an integer variable to that `UBatteryMan_SaveGame*` before calling `SaveGameToSlot ` and retrieving/printing that same integer variable in the `LoadInventory` method just for testing purposes?

Comment: I tested an int32 value in the game and it saves and carries to the next level, but inventory is still gone. AItem does inherit from AActor. When I add items to the inventory, the actor is destroyed, but the thumbnail and stats of the item are still visible/usable for the level they're attained in.

Comment: If I'm destroying the actor in the level, would that have something to do with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219704/discussion-between-christian-cook-and-chris-gong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you may have found out why the issue is occurring from our discussion in the comments, but I will try to finish our discussion with this answer. The problem is that you are trying to save an array of pointers to actors in a map. However, the actors in the map get destroyed once you call `UGameplayStatics::OpenLevel` in order to change the map. As a result, the pointers in that array end up pointing to garbage data, which is why your game is crashing.

Now, there are many ways to go about this, but you're ultimately going to have to save information about the actors and respawn them. What I have found on Unreal Engine forums is that a common approach is to create a custom struct of type `FArchive` for information about these actors, in your case about instances of `AItem`. For example, a struct called `AItemInfo` which will store info such as the actor's class, the actor's transform, the actor's name, etc., as well as a `TArray` member representing a serialized bytestream of other data from an actor (`AItem`). Then, serialize the actor into that struct's `TArray` member variable using a `FMemoryWriter` object. Note that typically you wouldn't serialize all the information about actor, only specific variables/properties marked with the `SaveGame` property specifier when you set the `ArIsSaveGame` variable in your struct to true. After doing that for each `AItem` instance you want to keep track of, you can store each instance of this `AItemInfo` struct in an array defined in your custom `USaveGame` class. In your case, it's `UBatteryMan_SaveGame`. Then, you can call `UGameplayStatics::SaveGameToSlot` on your `UBatteryMan_SaveGame` instance that contains the array of information structs. When you load that `UBatteryMan_SaveGame` instance, you can deserialize the array/sequence of bytes in each `AItemInfo` struct in the array with a `FMemoryReader` object in order to get the actor information in addition to the other stuff already in the struct and use all of that information to recreate each actor you need from the original map.

Here are a couple of good links that can help you get started:

- https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/35618/savingloading-an-array-of-objects.html
- https://www.ue4community.wiki/legacy/savegame-pointers-and-structs-8wlg0qms
- [Another approach to saving game data](https://www.ue4community.wiki/Legacy/Save_System,_Read_%26_Write_Any_Data_to_Compressed_Binary_Files)